# Empty folders when file is deleted using CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid, carrierwave

When I delete an uploaded file using CarrierWave and Mongoid it remove the file but leave emty folders.

```
/files/:user_id/images/:file_id/ ['image.png', 'content_image.png', 'thumb_image.png']
```

I want the `:file_id` folder to also be removed when the file is deleted. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved this with this:

```
  before_destroy :remember_id
  after_destroy :remove_id_directory

  protected

  def remember_id
    @id = id
  end

  def remove_id_directory
    FileUtils.remove_dir("#{Rails.root}/path/to/folder/#{@id}", :force => true)
  end
```

Comment: where do you place this? in the uploader? or on the model?

Comment: after_destroy seems to fit in the model: `undefined method 'after_destroy' for ImportUploader:Class`

Comment: @user1055045 - we do not need two callbacks, since after_destroy still have access to id.

Comment: BE CAREFUL! make sure that the path you tell `remove_dir` to blow away, matches whatever you intend to delete.  An extra IF statement around that `remove_dir` statement does not hurt. ;)

Comment: wow,,, it delete all file for me.. what if I want to delete only specific file?

Comment: @JenuelGanawed if your only removing the file then https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#removing-uploaded-files

Comment: @dft oh the problem is im not using view of ruby,, Im using it as backend for our vue project. Is their any way. Is their any function for ruby that can do that, so that I can only add it it my controller functions?

Comment: That shouldn't matter. If you're doing it in a form, you can send the same param to destroy it. Or if you have a separate action just to delete an attachment you can use `model.remove_avatar!` in your backend where "avatar" is your uploader attachment.

Answer (score 4):

You can run a daily cron job to wipe out the directories:

```
cd /your/uploads/dir && find . -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;
```

Comment: What speaks against this? I will go with this solution. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can also do like this:

```
after_destroy :remove_file_directory


 def remove_file_directory
    path = File.expand_path(mount.store_path, mount.root)
    FileUtils.remove_dir(path, force: false)
 end
```

Where **mount is what you have mounted_as** Eg: if you have `mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader` then

```
 def remove_file_directory
    path = File.expand_path(avatar.store_path, avatar.root)
    FileUtils.remove_dir(path, force: false)
 end
```

Comment: and what if for some strange reason path is / ? 
Better put a safeguard around that `remove_dir`